# How to zoom in and out a fotorama gallery

Tags: fotorama

On the website i create a drawer opens and a gallery comes out. It ist starting at size (0,0) and zooms to the middle of the screen, controlled by JS:

```
$(id).css("z-index", "4").stop().animate({
    "top" : rect.top + "px",
    "left" : rect.left + "px",
    "height" : rect.height + "px",
    "width" : rect.width + "px"
}, step_dauer * duration, easing);
```

This way, the div zooms as desired, but the fotorama inside does not: the main image and the thumb-nails keep their size.

So instead of a **thumb-nail of the fotorama** i see just a **cutout of the fotorama**.

So, my question is:

How can i let the gallery appear out of the drawer in an authentic way?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried selecting the id of the  inside the gallery? Rather than `$("#idOfGallery")` you could try `$("#idOfGallery img")` or even `$("#idOfGallery img").first()`.

Hope this helps.